# Can't get data from an SQLite database in Qt Mac os

Tags: macos, qt, sqlite

I've got a problem:

Connected to the SQLite database, written a request

```
#include "schedule_edit.h"
#include "ui_schedule_edit.h"
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <functions.h>
#include <QStringListModel>

Schedule_edit::Schedule_edit(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::Schedule_edit)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);

  ui->tableWidget->setColumnWidth(1, 150);

  QStringList list;
  model = new QStringListModel();

  QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
  db.setDatabaseName("/Users/andreymityulin/Desktop/S2.sqlite");

  QSqlQuery query;

  if (db.isOpen())
  {

    query.exec("SELECT OVERALL FROM LESSONS_NAMES_5_9");

    QSqlRecord rec = query.record();

    while (query.next())
    {
        list << query.value(rec.indexOf("OVERALL")).toString();
    }

    model->setStringList(list);

    ui->listView->setModel(model);

    db.close();
  }

}
```

but I have no ideas why no data is received.
I ensure the path to DB is typed correctly.
Please, help me correct the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debug what's going on. Check if the query is executed correctly, or print the error. Also, you can access the first value simply by `value(0)`.

```
if(!query.exec("SELECT OVERALL FROM LESSONS_NAMES_5_9"))
{
    qDebug() << query.lastError().text(); 
}

while (query.next())
{
    list << query.value(0).toString();
}
```

UPDATE

---

Since the error is "out of memory Unable to execute statement", try preparing the query.

```
...
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("SELECT OVERALL FROM LESSONS_NAMES_5_9");

if(!query.exec())
{
    qDebug() << query.lastError().text(); 
}

while (query.next())
{
    list << query.value(0).toString();
}
```

UPDATE 2

---

Instead of *clearing* the query, you'd better create the `QSqlQuery` just before you need it. When it goes out of scope, it will automatically clear itself.

From QtDocs:

> void QSqlQuery::clear()
>
> Clears the result set and releases any resources held by the query. Sets the query state to inactive. You should rarely if ever need to call this function.

Comment: debugged, here's the message: "out of memory Unable to execute statement". I just wonder, what did I do wrong.

Comment: @AndrewRaiden see update, this should work as expected.

Comment: Understood. Grateful for the explanations!